# Why "git status" does not show update in remote bare repository while "pull" works well?

Tags: git

I have a bare repository set up in my remote ubuntu server. I can access it from both local repository and remote repository, including another repository in the same Ubuntu server with working area. The name of the repository is warehouse with only 1 branch named as "main" and as HEAD. The "master" branch has been deleted due to some unresolvable conflicts. I changed the name "master" to "main" in all repositories.

"git push" and "git pull" works perfectly. But after a new commision is pushed to the repository, "git status" shows "up to date" from all terminals. I expect I see updates from the bare repository. Anyway, "git pull" gets all updates correctly, and "git remote show xxx" shows "out of date" correctly. Why "git status" shows "up to date"?

```
local bash> git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'warehouse/main'. 

local bash> git remote show warehouse
* remote warehouse
  Fetch URL: xxx@xxxx.xxx:/path/to/git/
  Push  URL: xxx@xxxx.xxx:/path/to/git/
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branch:
    main tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    main merges with remote main
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    main pushes to main (up to date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git does not do anything automatically. A Git repo does not automatically "know" what's happening on a corresponding remote. It doesn't look at the corresponding remote until *you* give it a command that tells it to communicate with the remote.

`git push` is such a command. `git pull` is such a command. `git remote show` is such a command. But `git status` is not.

If you want a local Git to update its knowledge of what's going on at the corresponding remote, say `git fetch`.